# Math - Resizing Container Height According to Scalable and Fixed Objects

Tags: math

i'm try to determine the amount to scale down an image, which is in a container with other fixed height text fields, based on the resizing of a window to layout the container contents.

in this problem i'm only concerned about height, so when i mention scale, i'm refering to the height scale or `scaleY`.

in the diagram below:

1. Blue = Resizable main window.
2. Green = Resizable Container within main window.
3. Red = Fixed-height text fields (non-scalable).
4. Black = Scalable image.

   [image]

the contents (text fields and image) fill the container, so the green container can represent the height of the text fields and image, or at least the difference between the first text field's y coordinate and the last text field's y coordinate and height.

resizing the window larger than the green container will have no affect on the green container and it will remain its current size.  however, resizing the window smaller must change the container size to fit.  i only have access to the image height.  so resizing the window smaller will also scale the image height.  the new scaled image height will determine the height of the container that includes the fixed height text fields.

Problem:  after resizing the window to a lower height, how can i find out how much to scale the image (between 0.0 and 1.0) so that the fixed height text fields remain as distant from each other and the container is resized so its bounds remain equally distant (10px apart in this diagram) from the window.

```
image.scaleY = ...
```

Comment: Just find out the scale change on the window, and apply that to the image.  So if the window changed from `100px -> 80px is new/original = 80/100 = 0.8 = scale; new image height = old image height * scale`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing window size by `dh` pixel must also reduce the image height by `dh` pixel in order to maintain all other absolute values.

Thus, the scaling factor is (given `image_height` is the current image height and `dh` is the number of pixels to reduce)

```
scale_y = (image_height - dh) / image_height
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the height of the resizable window (green), and subtract the sum of the fixed height components and the spacing between the components. The remaining space is what's available for the salable image.

Of course most UI toolkits include some tools to make this easy for you, like a table or grid layout that supports fixed and scalable cells, or a dock layout. If you can you should take advantage of this kind of features since it trends to be more performant/responsive.

Comment: Oh, and then to determine the scale_y you just divide available_height by original_height.